# how to force get/copy the dependencies list from gdebi-gtk?

Tags: dependencies

If we try to install some package with `gdebi-gtk` and there are missing dependencies, when we click in "details" it will show a popup window.
It contains a tiny list field that we can barely read, the letters are big but the field is too small.
Anyway, the real problem is, despite we can select, we can't even copy it's contents.

So, how to force get it?

Answer (score 0):

first find it's pid:
`pgrep -fa gdebi-gtk #eg 3283`

dump it:
`sudo gcore 3283`

collect the package names:
`astr=($(strings core.3283 |grep "To be installed:" |sort -u |sed -r 's".*: ""' |grep -v "%s"))`

fix any if necessary:
`declare -p astr #copy this output, paste and edit`

install them
`sudo apt-get install "${astr[@]}"`

I just did it for 80 winehq (latest 5.8) dependencies w/o problems.